# NodeJS - multithreaded application database bottleneck

Tags: node.js, database, multithreading, sqlite

Im wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how best to implement an embedded database like sqlite3, for maximum performance in a multithreaded node application. i have something working currently but sqlite is the bottleneck it seems

i have worker child processes set up to create arrays of objects with properties that map 1:1 to columns in an sqlite db. ideally i want to be able to create as many of these workers per CPUs available so as to generate these arrays of objects as fast as possible, and so that when this application is run on a supercomputer it will experience significant speed increases.

the issue is once each worker has generated its array and passes it off to the database writing thread, the database write part is a huge bottleneck. even on  laptop the generate threads pass so much data to the db writer that it cant keep up, effectively making the extra threads useless in regards to reducing overall running time.

one of the biggest issues, as expected, is the serialized nature of sqlite writes. i cant have multiple db workers writing to the same db. i have thought about maybe making an sqlite db for each thread then merging at the end, though that would mean each threads db would likely contain many duplicates since it wont be checking the keys in the other threads dbs, or i would have to make each thread check each other threads dbs keys as well as its own before insert. doesnt seem ideal. ive also tried writing to the filesystem but that has a host of other issues

perhaps there is a better solution than sqlite? i have looked at hdf5 and a bunch of other solutions but im really not sure. any suggestions on the best way to write high volumes of data generated at maximum speed by multiple threads concurrently would be much appreciated

Comment: Given SQLite has to lock the DB file to perform writes, then yes any throughput you gain by scaling out your Node instances is effectively lost when they need to perform the writes. What's the purpose of the DB?

Comment: im generating peptide sequences which then need to be scored and sorted in a different application. having the sequences in a db makes them much easier to sort once the scoring is done, pick the top scorers etc.

also its an easy way to avoid duplicates, since the program generates sequences randomly, INSERT OR IGNORE ensures no duplicates are stored.

im not against using a different solution other than a db